# TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined at Object.addDishToCourse

Tags: javascript, typeerror

Really struggling figuring out what I'm doing wrong here, any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm getting this error below:

> this._courses[courseName].push(dish);
>
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
>       at Object.addDishToCourse

```
const menu = {
  _courses: {
    appetizers: [],
    mains: [],
    desserts: [],  
    get appetizers() {
      return this._courses.appetizers;
    },
    get mains() {
      return this._courses.mains;
    },
    get desserts() {
      return this._courses.desserts;
    },
    set appetizers(appetizers) {
      this._courses.appetizers = appetizers;
    },
    set mains(mains) {
      this._courses.mains = mains;
    },
    set desserts(desserts) {
      this._courses.desserts = desserts;
    }
  },
  get _courses() {
    return {
      appetizers: this.appetizers,
      mains: this.mains,
      desserts: this.desserts
    };
  },
  addDishToCourse (courseName, dishName, dishPrice) {
    const dish = {
      name: dishName,
      price: dishPrice
    };
    return this._courses[courseName].push(dish);
  },
  getRandomDishFromCourse(courseName) {
    const dishes = this._courses[courseName];
    const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * dishes.length);
    return dishes[randomIndex];
  },
  generateRandomMeal() {
    const appetizers = this.getRandomDishFromCourse('appetizers');
    const mains = this.getRandomDishFromCourse('mains');
    const desserts = this.getRandomDishFromCourse('desserts');
    const totalPrice = appetizers.price + mains.price + desserts.price 
    return `Your meal is $${totalPrice}.`;
  }
};

menu.addDishToCourse('appetizers', 'Ceaser Salad', 4.25);

let meal = menu.generateRandomMeal();
console.log(meal);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're locking up the `get appetizers()` getter inside the courses object. Therefore, when you try using it in `get _courses()` by calling only `this.appetizers` and not `this.courses.appetizers` you get back undefined.

**Original**

```
_courses: {
    appetizers: [],
        mains: [],
            desserts: [],
                get appetizers() {
        return this._courses.appetizers;
    },
    get mains() {
        return this._courses.mains;
    },
    get desserts() {
        return this._courses.desserts;
    },
    set appetizers(appetizers) {
        this._courses.appetizers = appetizers;
    },
    set mains(mains) {
        this._courses.mains = mains;
    },
    set desserts(desserts) {
        this._courses.desserts = desserts;
    }
}
```

**Solution**

Get those methods out of the courses object so it contains only the properties:

```
_courses: {
    appetizers: [],
    mains: [],
    desserts: []
},
```

The code should finally look something like this:

```
const menu = {
    _courses: {
        appetizers: [],
        mains: [],
        desserts: [],
        get appetizers() {
            return this._courses.appetizers;
        },
        get mains() {
            return this._courses.mains;
        },
        get desserts() {
            return this._courses.desserts;
        },
        set appetizers(appetizers) {
            this._courses.appetizers = appetizers;
        },
        set mains(mains) {
            this._courses.mains = mains;
        },
        set desserts(desserts) {
            this._courses.desserts = desserts;
        }
    },
    get _courses() {
        return {
            appetizers: this.appetizers,
            mains: this.mains,
            desserts: this.desserts
        };
    },
    addDishToCourse(courseName, dishName, dishPrice) {
        const dish = {
            name: dishName,
            price: dishPrice
        };
        return this._courses[courseName].push(dish);
    },
    getRandomDishFromCourse(courseName) {
        const dishes = this._courses[courseName];
        const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * dishes.length);
        return dishes[randomIndex];
    },
    generateRandomMeal() {
        const appetizers = this.getRandomDishFromCourse('appetizers');
        const mains = this.getRandomDishFromCourse('mains');
        const desserts = this.getRandomDishFromCourse('desserts');
        const totalPrice = appetizers.price + mains.price + desserts.price
        return `Your meal is $${totalPrice}.`;
    }
};

menu.addDishToCourse('appetizers', 'Ceaser Salad', 4.25);

let meal = menu.generateRandomMeal();
console.log(meal);
```

Comment: Thank you for the response.. but I'm not sure I understand. I'm not seeing a difference between your solution and mine.

Comment: You are including some getters and setters such as `get _appetizers()`  inside the courses object. Based on how you use it later in your code, it should be **outside** this object. To be more specific, you are calling `addDishToCourse()` which is calling `get _courses()`, and this is subsequently calling `get _appetizers()`. This getter is concretely called when you use `this.appetizers`. 
The problem is, as you can see, that since you have `get _appetizers()` **inside** the courses object, you would need to refactor your code, and use `this._courses.appetizers`.

Comment: I understand.. i ended up moving the getters and setters outside of the courses object. Seems to be working now! Thank you :)